# What is the life expectancy in The Culture series?

Tags: the-culture

So in *The Player of Games*, it said that one way to die is you can completely annihilate your brain, and that some guy fell off a cliff or something, and his brain just had to wait a few months to grow a new body.

Does that mean that people can more or less live forever? Because if they're sick or old they can just grow a new body, no?

Comment: I think the general idea is that they have effective immortality, but that actually choosing to use that to it's fullest extent is looked down upon, so most minds "retire" after a full (and fairly extended) life.  I have pretty much only read that one book as well though, so I don't know what to cite for that.

Comment: Interesting. I seemed to have missed why it is looked down upon? Presumably a similar reason to having lots of kids being looked down upon? But I don't understand that either since they live in post-scarcity, so surely they have the resources to do it...

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if I picked that up off the book or one of many Culture synopsis' I've seen.  I think it's mostly a matter of death not being feared, and not wishing to stagnate the society as a whole, not one of resources. (oh, and by the way, welcome to the site).

Comment: Thanks! Also, what do you mean by stagnate society?

Comment: @Gallifreyan Would that I could! I don't have the karma to upvote yet! :'(

Comment: Haha :) Sorry, forgot about this :)

Comment: @imu96: Probably 'science advances one funeral at a time'. And not just science, but culture too - what would the modern US be like if Washington and Jefferson and Adams were still the dominant political figures?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Typical life-expectancy in the Culture *in one's original body* is about 300-400 years.** Beyond that point, it's considered normal to choose either auto-euthenisation (approximately 50% of citizens choose this option) or a shift into some form of *functional immortality* either through the alteration of one's physical body, storage, a shift into a robot body, a shift into an entirely new physical form or (at the extreme end) sublimation.

> *Every Culture habitat - whether it was an Orbital or other large
> structure, a ship, a Rock, or a planet - possessed Storage facilities.
> Storage was where some people went when they had reached a certain
> age, or if they had just grown tired of living. **It was one of the
> choices that Culture humans faced towards the end of their
> artificially extended three-and-a-half to four centuries of life. They
> could opt for rejuvenation and/or complete immortality, they could
> become part of a group mind, they could simply die when the time came,
> they could transfer out of the Culture altogether, bravely accepting
> one of the open but essentially inscrutable invitations left by
> certain Elder civilisations, or they could go into Storage,** with
> whatever revival criterion they desired.*
>
> <sub><sup>Excession</sup></sub>

There's also the option of simply having a ship or hub mind alter your body and mind to cope with actual immortality. One of the characters is a man who's been effectively immortal in his natural form for nearly 10,000 years.

> ***He was around ten thousand years ago,** at the time of the negotiations
> which gave rise to the Culture in the first place. This individual was
> named as perhaps being able to help provide proof that what was
> claimed in the message to the Gzilt was actually true.*
>
> ∞
>
> *So, not long dissolved in some group-mind, then. Stored, I take it?*
>
> ∞
>
> ***Not Stored. In fact, never Stored. Still with us, still alive, still
> extant and functioning, twenty-five to thirty full lifetimes after
> you’d have expected any ordinary humanoid mortal to have decently
> abandoned the corporeal.** Indeed, longer-living than any known still
> independent Mind or even high-level AI from the time. Like the
> fucker’s decided to outlive everybody or set a record or something.
> But alive, somewhere, probably still within the Culture.*
>
> <sub><sup>The Hydrogen Sonata</sup></sub>

and

> **It was one of the effects of living in a society where people commonly
> lived for four centuries** and on average bore just over one child each
> that there were very few of their young around,
>
> <sub><sup>Look to Windward</sup></sub>

It's worth noting that for many citizens of the Culture, direct immortality is seen as slightly tacky. A choice that's made by people who're fundamentally immature in some way.

> *“Sma!” he exclaimed, turning to her. “That’s for you; it isn’t for me.
> **You think I’m wrong to have my age stabilized; even the chance of
> immortality is . . . wrong, to you. Okay, I can see that. In your
> society, the way you live your lives, of course it is. You have your
> three-fifty, four hundred years, and know you’ll get right to the end
> of them; die with your boots off.** For me . . . that won’t work.*
>
> <sub><sup>Use of Weapons</sup></sub>

---

Iain M. Banks discussed this aspect of Culture life in his essay (required reading!) "[A Few Notes on the Culture](http://www.vavatch.co.uk/books/banks/cultnote.htm)"

> Which brings us to the length of those generations, and the fact that
> they can be said to exist at all. H**umans in the Culture normally live
> about three-and-a-half to four centuries.** The majority of their lives
> consists of a three-century plateau which they reach in what we would
> compare to our mid-twenties, after a relatively normal pace of
> maturation during childhood, adolescence and early adulthood. They age
> very slowly during those three hundred years, then begin to age more
> quickly, then they die.
>
> ...
>
> None of this, of course, is compulsory (nothing in the Culture is compulsory). **Some people choose biological immortality; others have their personality transcribed into AIs and die happy feeling they continue to exist elsewhere; others again go into Storage, to be woken in more (or less) interesting times, or only every decade, or century, or aeon, or over exponentially increasing intervals,** or only when it looks like something really different is happening...